# How do I use currying with an arbitrary number of arguments in Racket?

Tags: arguments, scheme, racket, currying

Let's say I want to define a function like `format` in curried syntax. How would I handle the additional arguments that could be passed through? For example, I would want to be able to do something like the following:

`(((format "~a ~a") 5) 9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's tricky. The question is how `format` is supposed to know that it's got all of its arguments. I'm guessing that you're hoping that format will parse its output string and determine how many arguments it needs, then fire when it's received the right number of arguments. You're going to wind up rolling it yourself. Something like this (NOTE: UNTESTED CODE):

```
#lang racket

;; given a format-string, return a curried function that
;; accepts the format-string's arguments one at a time
(define (curried-format fmt-str)
  (define num-args-expected (count-format-string-args fmt-str))
  (define (so-far->waiter so-far)
    (lambda (arg)
      (define new-args (cons arg so-far))
      ;; do we have all of the args?
      (if (= (length new-args) num-args-expected)
          ;; yay! call format:
          (apply format fmt-str (reverse new-args))
          ;; nope: wait for some more:
          (so-far->waiter new-args))))
  (so-far->waiter '()))
```

Comment: Oof, that's quite heavy. I guess for the purpose of formatting and printing/writing strings, an approach like this will work. I'm curious, though, what if you had no idea how many arguments the function will take in? Would such a situation be even possible under the current currying syntax rules?

Comment: How would the curried function know when to fire?

Comment: That's why I didn't think it would work. I was hoping it could be handled by something like the `(define (f . l) ...)` syntax where you have an arbitrary number of arguments and you can just call a function on the list using `apply`.